# What are the most and least active day period on Stackoverflow?

Tags: discussion

Simply, in what period of day (UTC time range) the most and the least number of experts are online and are answering questions. I guess this information is available to the most high-ranked persons with reputation score starting from 25000. Is it somehow possible for usual stackoverflow user to see what period of day is most active so that he can post his question in the most active time range. I (as a typical Stackoverflow user) would prefer to post my question in the most active time range and not in least active. Obviously, this indicator is very variable, but if not take into account those users who only ask questions and new users, I guess there will be clear pattern. Well, even just knowing time range of most active period of day regardless of the type of users (experts or new users) would be useful for me. Is it possible to see this statistics for typical Stackoverflow users?

Comment: Weekends are usually slow...odd that. :>)

Comment: MSE duplicate: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/1313

Comment: 7 years passed since 2009. I am pretty sure it is no longer actual information.

Comment: I am not asking for different opinions of different users about most active time. I am asking if a user can get such statistics like in question that approxiblue provided. Therefore it is clearly not opinion based.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/213603/question-and-answer-activity-on-stackexchange-interactive-and-customized-editio